# Detecting null values in dataframe show as zero in Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code to print number of null values in each column of dataframe df1 using pandas:

```
df1.isnull().sum(axis = 0)
```

The output shows that all values in some columns are null but when I open my CSV file using Excel they are all zero.
Is there a problem with this library or my code is wrong?

Comment: are you replacing the 0 to nan in any preceding steps? if not this sounds weird

Comment: No. Is excel showing null values as 0?

Comment: Can you share a sample content of `df1` and how you are reading the csv file ?